# Passing option value to onSubmit?

Tags: javascript

I have a form being rendered in a React component. Inside the form are an `input` field, an `option` dropdown, and a `button` to submit.

Basically when the button is clicked, I want to pass the selected option into the `onSubmit` handler, which in the code below is `chef.id`.

The problem is, all the chef objects are mapped inside the form, and I'm not sure how to extract the selected chef, to pass into `onSubmit`.

I didnt use `this` for the event listener methods because I'm using redux, though I suppose that's not relevant to this particular problem.

```
return (
  <div className="form-input">  
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitRecipes(**chef.id**)}>
      <input onChange={handleChange}/>
      <select>
        {chefs.map(chef => <option value={chef.name}>{chef.name}</option>)}
      </select>
      <button>Create</button>      
    </form>
  </div>
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add an `onChange` event to the `select` element as well, and change the value of the `option` elements to be the `chef.id`
then in your `onChange` handler you can get the chef id like so `e.target.value` and update you state.
then in your `handleSubmitRecipes` you can get it from the state.

Comment: ah thank you. I was just exactly thinking about putting the selected into state as well. Though I didn't know you could put onChange on the select tag. Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!
glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try some original DOM operations, maybe below codes can help you.

```
<form>
    <input name="name" />
    <select name="age">
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
      <option>30</option>
    </select>
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>

const [form] = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      console.log(form.age.value);
      console.log(form.name.value);
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```